# Monitoring and scaling WebSphere AS on Amazon WS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websphere, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a web app in AWS server with WebSphere Application Server.

1. Is this possible to monitor:

   - WebSphere Applicaiton Server server status capacity monitoring?
   - uptime using Amazon CloudWatch metrics?
2. Can Autoscaling handle load balancing of a individual application server as well? Or should we do that by ourselves?

Update:

1. so you (Jeevan Dongre) mean to say ELB is good enough to handle multiple AWS instances of same web app ( For Ex. running 3 diffirent apps servers in 3 AWS instances ).
2. ELB can report and handle the instances but not the app servers health status?, how this can be handled ?

3.On the cost wise, I would need to run 3-4 instances when i go for ELB? but i can run 4 app servers in two AWS instances using app server load balancing.

Please advise which is good to go and make the decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of tools available to monitor your ec2 instance, I personally use monit and munin along with pagerduty and pingdom which sends alert and also phone calls during downtime.
You can use the same tools or use GOD, nagios and many other tools to monitor your app server because most of the monitoring tools gives the flexibility to monitor what ever you want.

Load balancer handles the traffic according to the least number of connections to instance. I dont think the app server load balancing is required when you have only one app running in one instance. ELB is smart enough to access the health of your instance and divert the traffic according, also a very honest suggestion make sure your app os state less and do not your stick session. It will impact a load on your app's performance. AWS its self suggests this.

If you like to handle the health of the app servers you can use monit, monit basically helps to monitor the desired app server and take necessary actions according to that.

Load balancing between the multiple app servers has to be done manually.

But I am bit skeptical about running multiple app servers in the same instance and load balancing between them, instead what I did is, I am running running only one app server but I am spawning multiple threads if I get more traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will check for monit, munin and GOD as well, then I will find the suitable one for my need.
My app has suspected to have around 600 to 1200 concurrent users so I would need to handle the load balancing. Please see my Updated question regarding it.

Comment: I couldnt paste a long reply. Please see my updated part in my question

Comment: Again thanks for the update. Can you please explain me how you spawned  multiple threads? Links and a bit more explanation would be great!

Comment: I work on ruby on rails based applications either passenger or unicorn which are app servers allows to specify the number of app instances to be created or spawned , I am not sure about websphere as such.